# Laravel Fill form with database saved fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

this below code is my profile managment form for users and i want to fill `input` tags with `$profile` variable .

`{{ $profile }}` can echo all fields of user table. but i can not fill `input` tags with this variable.

Result:   `{"id":"1","username":"mahdi","name":"Mahdi","family":"Pishguy","email":"name@gmail.com"}`

My Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'admin.profile.update', $profile->id , 'method' => 'PUT','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-right', 'role' =>'search')) }}
                <div class="form-group rtl">
                    <div>Your Username: <b> {{ $profile->username }} </b></div><br />
                    {{ Form::label('name' , 'name: ') }}
                    {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('id'=>'email', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}

                    {{ Form::label('family' , 'family: ') }} 
                    {{ Form::text('family', Input::old('family'), array('placeholder'=>'sss', 'id'=>'email', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}

                    <p>
                    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('id'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-default' , 'style'=>'float:left')) }}
                    </p>
                </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats easy, see the [Form Model Binding in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding)

You code should be something like this:

```
{{ Form::model($profile, array('route' => 'admin.profile.update', $profile->id , 'method' => 'PUT','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-right', 'role' =>'search')) }}
                <div class="form-group rtl">
                    <div>Your Username: <b> {{ $profile->username }} </b></div><br />
                    {{ Form::label('name' , 'name: ') }}
                    {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('id'=>'email', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}

                    {{ Form::label('family' , 'family: ') }} 
                    {{ Form::text('family', Input::old('family'), array('placeholder'=>'sss', 'id'=>'email', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}

                    <p>
                    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('id'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-default' , 'style'=>'float:left')) }}
                    </p>
                </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

NOTE: You can remove the `Input::old()` stuf because this is handled by the `Form::model()`

Comment: You should just remove Input::old() from the code snippet altogether because like you mention, it's not even necessary.